# Insert tab space in title of contents text

Tags: titletoc

I have sections with names that follow the format   and some of the numbers are longer than others.  When the table of contents is created, the  portions are not aligned.  For example, with the attached MWE, the table of contents looks like this:
[image]

I would like the table of contents to look like this:
[image]

I appears as though you cannot insert \tab (e.g. from tabto package) into a table of contents.  I tried with titletoc or toctoft packages.  Is there another way to achieve this?

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath, titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[1em]{}{}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[]

% Document
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section[PT12345678 Sample Section]{Sample Section}
\lipsum[1]
\section[PT123456789876543 Second Sample Section]{Second Sample Section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: The solution works. You can see the output from my system. I tried with lualatex and pdflatex. Please try my exact code in a new empty directory. Second step: update your system.

Comment: That the solution works is before your eyes. Are you using a different setup or preamble? You get the wrong output and/or LaTeX error messages? Please expand your question with new information to find a better a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** It can be done using the tabular environment. I defined a new commands with two parameters.

[image: a]

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath, titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[1em]{}{}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[]

\newlength{\colw}
\setlength{\colw}{10em} %adjust to fit the longest entry

\newcommand{\ctocx}[2]{%% entry to TOC with two parameters
\protect
\begin{tabular}{ll} 
    \parbox{\colw}{#1} &#2 \\
\end{tabular}}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    
    \newpage
    \section[\ctocx{PT12345678}{Sample Section}]{Sample Section}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section[\ctocx{PT123456789876543}{Second Sample Section}]{Second Sample Section}
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the MWE was overly simplified.  There will be anywhere from 50-75 different sections from a list of about 125 possible sections.  Your proposed approach would require 125 different custom commands similar to \ctoci and that would be hard to maintain because the library of sections that this pulls from changes frequently (e.g. new editions of sections with new section numbers).  And the issue with trying to use one command with parameters is that anything within the [ ] after \section cannot contain parameters (at least that is what seems to be the case).

Comment: @rsgny I this is your real problem, its is better define a command with two arguments.. See the updated answer.

Comment: This solution does not work, for the same reason that a simple \tab (using tabto package) doesn't work - there are restrictions on what can be inside the \section <option> in \section[<option>].  One of those restrictions is that you can't call any command that has parameters.  It's less clear why \tab doesn't work, but I've tried it and it does not work.  I also tried the proposed solution above and it does not work either.

Comment: @rsgny That the solution works is before your eyes. Are you using a different setup or preamble? You get the wrong output and/or LaTeX error messages? Please expand your question with new information to find a better a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I create a macro `\Plabel` that sets the argument, left aligned, in a 1.5 inch box, essentially acting like a tab.

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath, titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[1em]{}{}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[]
\newcommand\Plabel[1]{\makebox[1.5in][l]{#1}}
% Document
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section[\Plabel{PT12345678} Sample Section]{Sample Section}
\lipsum[1]
\section[\Plabel{PT123456789876543} Second Sample Section]{Second Sample Section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What to do if I want to change the title from Content to Summary?

Comment: @BeneditoFreire Then replace `\tableofcontents` with `\section*{Summary}
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{toc}
\makeatother`